# How to code html5/PHP/JS/JQuery so that we can resize or crop images in iPad's Safari?

Tags: ios, html, image, ipad, safari

I have a website that allows user to upload images onto website via mobile safari, iOS6. Problem is that i can't find a way to allow users to crop the images.

Anyone has any solution?